# deploy a contract through a web UI

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, javascript

I was wondering what is the best approach to deploy a contract through a web UI. I am using meteor as framework and geth version 1.7 so i was thinking of using fs in my javascript to create a textfile on the server side with the contract and then writing some script so the contract would compile solidity automatically but then I need to do the following in geth console and i am not sure how it could be done automatically

```
 var abi = <abi from solc>;
 var myContract = eth.contract(abi); 
 var bytecode = '0x' + <bytecode from solc>;
 var txDeploy = {from:eth.coinbase, data: bytecode, gas: 1000000}; 
 var myContractPartialInstance = myContract.new(txDeploy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://remix.ethereum.org/. And github of remix: https://github.com/ethereum/remix

You can build your own dapp for deploying smart contract with web3js library and more.